# Using an OR Statement within a Return Where

Tags: c#, linq

I have this return Statement,

```
return taskItems.Where(s => s.DateCreated >= fromDate.SelectedDate || s.DateCreated <= toDate.SelectedDate);
```

This should work, but Visual Studio is giving me this exception on the "*InitializeComponent();*",

```
 Object reference not set to an instance of an object.
```

This is what's used to load the tasks into the Datagrid being used,

```
private IEnumerable<TaskEntry> LoadTasks()
    {
        var data = GetListItems("Tasks");
        var result = XElement.Parse(data.OuterXml);
        XNamespace z = "#RowsetSchema";
        var taskItems = from r in result.Descendants(z + "row")



                        //where r.Attribute("ows_Created") 
                        //where r.Attribute("ows_Client_x0020_Issue") == null

                        select new TaskEntry 
                        {
                            ID = r.Attribute("ows_ID") != null ? r.Attribute("ows_ID").Value : string.Empty,
                            IssueID = r.Attribute("ows_Client_x0020_Issue") != null ? r.Attribute("ows_Client_x0020_Issue").Value : string.Empty,
                            Client = r.Attribute("ows_Client") != null ? r.Attribute("ows_Client").Value : string.Empty,
                            Title = r.Attribute("ows_Title") != null ? r.Attribute("ows_Title").Value : string.Empty,
                            TaskType = r.Attribute("ows_Task_x0020_Type") != null ? r.Attribute("ows_Task_x0020_Type").Value : string.Empty,
                            Priority = r.Attribute("ows_Priority") != null ? r.Attribute("ows_Priority").Value : string.Empty,
                            Status = r.Attribute("ows_Status") != null ? r.Attribute("ows_Status").Value : string.Empty,
                            AssignedTo = r.Attribute("ows_AssignedTo") != null ? r.Attribute("ows_AssignedTo").Value : string.Empty,
                            Owner = r.Attribute("ows_Owner") != null ? r.Attribute("ows_Owner").Value : string.Empty,
                            Body = r.Attribute("ows_Body") != null ? r.Attribute("ows_Body").Value : string.Empty,
                            DueDate = Convert.ToDateTime(r.Attribute("ows_DueDate").Value).Date,
                            DateCreated = Convert.ToDateTime(r.Attribute("ows_Created").Value).Date,
                            Area = r.Attribute("ows_Area") != null ? r.Attribute("ows_Area").Value : string.Empty,
                            GroupTask = r.Attribute("ows_Group_x0020_Task") != null ? r.Attribute("ows_Group_x0020_Task").Value : string.Empty,
                        };

        return taskItems.Where(s => s != null && (s.DateCreated >= fromDate.SelectedDate || s.DateCreated <= toDate.SelectedDate));
    }
```

Comment: it could be there is a `null` object in your `taskItems`.

Comment: Could you show us where is this error throwing?

Comment: Without the code constructor of your form and what you do there is just an exercise in guessing

Comment: Try: `return taskItems.Where( s => s != null && (s.DateCreated >= fromDate.SelectedDate || s.DateCreated <= toDate.SelectedDate));`

Comment: I'll add more information now

Comment: Are u sure that taskItems is not null? or some of its members doesn't have dateCreated?

Comment: another possible cause is `fromDate` or `toDate` is null

Comment: @KhanhTO Wouldn't your suggested code fix the problem if this was so?

Comment: i would say: `return taskItems.Where(s => (fromDate == null || s.DateCreated >= fromDate.SelectedDate) && (toDate == null || s.DateCreated <= toDate.SelectedDate));`

Comment: @SandroPerez Take a break point in the line that is throwing the error and see if `taskItems`, `fromDate` or `toDate` are null...

Comment: I also changed the `||` to `&&` because i think you need `fromDate` to `toDate `. Using `&&` makes more sense here.

Comment: I ask again, where do you call this code? Show the path that leads to this method. What kind of controls are fromDate and toDate? What kind of application is? (Asp.NET, WinForms, WPF)

Comment: @KhanhTO Might seem like a dumb questions but, how would I be able to show the results that ranged from the two dates 'fromDate', 'toDate'

Answer (score 0):

You need to check that that values you are using for date filters are actually set. It would seem either fromDate or toDate are null or though without seeing some more code it is hard to say?